# SQL add comma sepeared values of a column

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table

```
  Column 1 | Column 2
  --------------------
  1,2,3,   |    abc
  2,3,4,   |    xyz
  1,       |    cc
  1,2,     |    aa
```

I want a query which sums up these comma separated values in vertica

```
  Column 1|Column 2
  --------|---------
  6       |  abc
  9       |  xyz
  1       |  cc
  3       |  aa
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Why are you storing comma delimited values in a column? Don't do that. Fix your data model and what you want is as simple as `select column_2, sum(column_1) from the_table group by column_2;`

Comment: Sure this was answered many times for any dbms https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+comma+separated+values+

Answer (score 1):

Solution for SQL Server

```
select col2, sum(cast(value as int)) FROM tab
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(col1, ',')
GROUP BY col2;
```

[SQL Server demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=efebb7cc364d8398ca4ce435cb5c9782)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for Postgres

```
select column_2, sum(t.x) as column_1
from the_table
  cross join lateral unnest(split_to_array(column_1,',')::int[]) as t(x)
group by column_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In vertica you can use [regexp_count](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_COUNT.htm)

example:

```
dbadmin=> select REGEXP_COUNT('1,2,3,4,' , ',');
 REGEXP_COUNT
--------------
            4
(1 row)
```

Comment: i want the sum of those columns it gives count